# File manager connections backup

Tags: ssh, filemanager, sftp

I'm web developer, sometimes I work with different machines, so I'd love to have a file of file manager sftp and other types connections.
Where can I find it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.